# Gradle spring boot with assembly module

Tags: java, gradle, spring-boot

I'm new to Gradle and I'm facing a problem ( using Gradle 2.14)

My project has 3 subprojects: assembly, sprinBootProject, E2E
The assembly module is responsible of zipping the jar of the spring boot application along with properties files.
The E2E module is an 'end to end' tests module for testing the spring boot application.

I'm using the distribution plugin in assembly/build.gradle like this:

```
apply plugin: 'distribution'

distributions {
    main {
        baseName "project-assembly"
        contents{
            from project(':springBootProject').fileTree(dir: 'build/libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            from project(':springBootProject').fileTree(dir: 'build/resources/main', includes: ['*.properties', 'conf/*.properties'])
        }
    }
}
```

but I need to make sure that springBootProject will be evaluated before the assembly subproject, so I used dependsOn like that:

```
distZip.dependsOn(':springBootProject:build')
```

when I added this line I see that the E2E module is failing in compileTestJava task, so this line is effecting how the spring boot application is generated (I think)

E2E/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile project(":springBootProject")
}
```

so my question is am I doing it right? why when I added the dependsOn line the E2E module is effected, and how can I force Gradle to evaluate the spring boot application before the assembly module?

Comment: Same type of issue is happen here in this tutorial: [Configuring the Dependency Configurations of Our Integration Tests](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out.
Gradle will evaluate modules by alphabetic order
so the evaluation will be: assembly -> E2E -> springBootProject 
when adding this line to assembly/build.gradle:

```
distZip.dependsOn(':springBootProject:build')
```

the order of the evaluation changed to be: assembly -> springBootProject -> E2E

now in 'springBootProject' module I am using the spring boot plugin in order to generate an executable jar, this executable jar is generated by the task :springBootProject:bootRepackage which uses the jar generated by the :springBootProject:jar task and convert it to executable.

now because the 'E2E' module depends on 'springBootProject' it will use it's jar, but now this jar is executable, and because of that I had a compilation error in 'E2E'.

so I have to make sure that the 'E2E' module gets the original jar and not the executable one.
so I added this line in springBootProject/build.gradle:

```
bootRepackage.mustRunAfter(':E2E:test')
```

which seem to solve the problem